# Is it possible to disable mods without removing them?

Tags: mods, stardew-valley

I currently have a number of mods in Stardew Valley set up, but I would occasionally like to play with them disabled.

Is there an easy way to disable them (preferably in-game) without removing them (and losing all the settings / risking corrupting other save games)?

I recall seeing a mod for this somewhere, but I couldn't find anything suitable while googling on how to do this (with or without a mod).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[StarDew Valley ModManager](https://www.nexusmods.com/stardewvalley/mods/21) is exactly what you're asking for.

If you dont want to use it, you can always move the mod's folder in another subfolder (such as "Disabled mods" for example).